# apache2 installation on linux:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Tags: apache2, linux-mint

i'm trying to install Apache on my Linux via terminal. used commands like 
"`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`"
and 
"`sudo apt-get install apache2`"

i'm getting the error

> "Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 `apache2 : Depends: apache2-bin (= 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.8)` but it is not going to be installed

```
Depends: apache2-utils (>= 2.4)
```

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.